# CSS only slideshow does not show pictures

Tags: html, css

I've found a pure CSS banner slider that is works good in code pen. I've copied the code of HTML and CSS into one page but it does not work. All of the images are external and they available. It has no any Js or etc just html and css. You may see it perfectly works here [CSS only slideshow](https://codepen.io/lgrqvst/pen/YdVLrE?editors=1111) Help me please.

```
<head>
</head>

<style>
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slideshow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);

  &--hero {
    z-index: 3;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    // width: 100%;
    height: 85%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) skewY(-10deg);
    transform-origin: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);

    .slides {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: -10%;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      animation: 11s slideshow-hero-mobile -3s infinite;
    }

    .slide1 {
      background-image: url(2.jpg);
      animation: 20s slides-set-1 -0.1s infinite;
    }
    .slide2 {
      background-image: url(3.jpg);
      animation: 20s slides-set-2 -0.1s infinite;
    }
    .slide3 {
      background-image: url(4.jpg);
      animation: 20s slides-set-3 -0.1s infinite;
    }

    @media (min-width: 600px) {
      left: 50%;
      top: 0;
      width: 67%;
      height: 100%;
      transform: translateX(-50%) skewX(-10deg);

      .slides {
        top: 0;
        left: -25%;
        height: 100%;
        animation: 11s slideshow-hero -3s infinite;
      }
    }
  }

  &--contrast {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    transform: none;
    
    .slide {
      filter: blur(3px);
    }

    &--before {
      left: 0;

      .slides {
        width: 100vw;
      }
    }

    &--after {
      z-index: 2;
      left: auto;
      right: 0;

      .slides {
        width: 100vw;
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
      }
    }

    .slides {
      animation: 14s slideshow-contrast -5s infinite;
    }

    .slide1 {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(200,200,75,0.25) 0, rgba(200,75,80,0.5) 100%), url(https://source.unsplash.com/1000x750);
      // background-image: url(../img/slideshow/hero-1.jpg);
      animation: 20s slides-set-1 -0.2s infinite;
    }
    .slide2 {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(200,200,75,0.25) 0, rgba(50,50,50,0.5) 100%), url(https://source.unsplash.com/1001x751);
      // background-image: url(../img/slideshow/hero-2.jpg);
      animation: 20s slides-set-2 -0.2s infinite;
    }
    .slide3 {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(100,100,75,0.25) 0, rgba(50,50,50,0.5) 100%), url(https://source.unsplash.com/1002x752);
      // background-image: url(../img/slideshow/hero-3.jpg);
      animation: 20s slides-set-3 -0.2s infinite;
    }

    &--after {
      top: auto;
      bottom: 0;

      .slides {
        animation: 13s slideshow-contrast -13s infinite;
      }
      .slide {
        background-position: right;
      }
      .slide1 {
        animation: 20s slides-set-1 infinite;
      }
      .slide2 {
        animation: 20s slides-set-2 infinite;
      }
      .slide3 {
        animation: 20s slides-set-3 infinite;
      }
    }

    @media (min-width: 600px) {
      width: 50%;
      height: 100%;

      &--after {
        top: 0;
        bottom: auto;

        .slides {
          width: 50vw;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

.slides,
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes slideshow-hero-mobile {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) skewY(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.05) skewY(10deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) skewY(10deg);
  }
}

@keyframes slideshow-hero {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) skewX(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.05) skewX(10deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) skewX(10deg);
  }
}

@keyframes slideshow-contrast {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
}

@keyframes slides-set-1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    // transform: translateY(0);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  31% {
    opacity: 1;
    // transform: translateY(0);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  34% {
    opacity: 0;
    // transform: translateY(100px);
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  97% {
    opacity: 0;
    // transform: translateY(-100px);
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    // transform: translateY(0);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes slides-set-2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    // transform: translateY(-100px);
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  31% {
    opacity: 0;
    // transform: translateY(-100px);
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  34% {
    opacity: 1;
    // transform: translateY(0);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  64% {
    opacity: 1;
    // transform: translateY(0);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  67% {
    opacity: 0;
    // transform: translateY(100px);
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    // transform: translateY(100px);
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
}
@keyframes slides-set-3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    // transform: translateY(-100px);
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  64% {
    opacity: 0;
    // transform: translateY(-100px);
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  67% {
    opacity: 1;
    // transform: translateY(0);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  97% {
    opacity: 1;
    // transform: translateY(0);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    // transform: translateY(100px);
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
}
</style>

<html>
<body>
    asdasd
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="slideshows">
  <div class="slideshow slideshow--hero">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="slide slide1"></div>
      <div class="slide slide2"></div>
      <div class="slide slide3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow slideshow--contrast slideshow--contrast--before">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="slide slide1"></div>
      <div class="slide slide2"></div>
      <div class="slide slide3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow slideshow--contrast slideshow--contrast--after">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="slide slide1"></div>
      <div class="slide slide2"></div>
      <div class="slide slide3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe try it with different images. If I open the image link it says `image not available`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this css link.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/10up-sanitize.css/8.0.0/sanitize.min.css">
```

Also this is a SCSS codepen, not css. If you want the css to work you have to convert it

https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css

Comment: Thank you very much! SCSS to CSS and everything works well!

Comment: Awesome to hear!

Answer (score 1):

Your `html`

tag needs to be at the start of your code for the css part to function properly .